# Step through multiple arrays in parallel with FOREACH

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array

Is it possible to loop over multiple array with `FOREACH` in PL/pgSQL? In my case, 3 arrays with identical dimensions. How can I pass the elements like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++){
  my_method(array1[i], array2[i], array3[i]);
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
select dugong.session_hugeInsert( 3, '5,2,3,1', '4,3,3,2');
```

> ```
> NOTICE:  The transaction is in an uncommitable state.Transaction was rolled back.
> NOTICE:  query "SELECT Question_ID, UserResponseID_List, UserResponseList" returned 3 columns 42601
> ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
> HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dugong.session_hugeinsert(integer,text,text) line 61 at SQL statement
> ```

My function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Dugong.Session_hugeInsert(
    Quiz_ID_ int,       --FK
    QuestionList_ TEXT,
    UserResponseList_ TEXT
)
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
    Session_ID integer;
    QuestionList INT[];
    Question_ID integer;
    QuizQuestionisDone boolean;
    UserResponseList INT[];
    UserResponseID_List INT[];  -- Get from database
    UserResponseID integer;
    tmp int;

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dugong.quiz WHERE quiz_id = Quiz_ID_ ) THEN

    QuestionList = string_to_array(QuestionList_, ',');
    UserResponseList = string_to_array(UserResponseList_, ',');
    FOREACH UserResponseID in ARRAY UserResponseList
    LOOP
        tmp := Dugong.UserResponse_Add();
        UserResponseID_List :=array_append(UserResponseID_List, tmp );
    END LOOP;  -- Memo: Got UserResponseID_List array

    FOREACH Question_ID, UserResponseID, tmp IN ARRAY Question_ID, UserResponseID_List, UserResponseList
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', QuestionList[i], UserResponseID_List[i], UserResponseList[i] ;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 200;

    ELSE
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

My first solution does not seem very good:

```
i:=0; j:=0; k:=0;
FOREACH Question_ID IN ARRAY QuestionList
LOOP
    j := 0;
    FOREACH UserResponseID IN ARRAY UserResponseID_List
    LOOP
        k := 0;
        FOREACH tmp IN ARRAY UserResponseList
            LOOP
        IF (i = j AND j = k) THEN
           RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', Question_ID, UserResponseID, tmp;
        END IF;
        k := k+1;
            END LOOP;
    j := j+1;
    END LOOP;
i := i + 1;
END LOOP;
```

Please let me know the proper way to go.

Comment: The error looks like it has nothing to do with the question above. Please show your plpgsql code.

Comment: @DanielVérité Here you are. I have to clean my code. I am preparing for worst case I will use count index i, j, and k. Loop over them and IF(i==j and j==k) my_function(.....);

Comment: Explicit ROLLBACK in a function is not allowed and is the default outcome anyway. I would remove the entire exception block. What it does now is: in case of any error, report and raise the error. But this is just what happens when there's no custom exception handling.

Comment: @DanielVérité. New knowledge! How can I use ROLLBACK properly in my PLPGSQL code? In my opinion any complete (already committed) transaction in plpgsql is unable to do ROLLBACK. Am I right?

Comment: You cannot use `ROLLBACK` inside plpgsql ***at all***, like @Daniel already told you. A plpgsql block is *always* inside a transaction automatically. Any untrapped error will roll back everything automatically.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you. I will clean my code from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While [`FOREACH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) is very convenient to loop through a *single array*, it's not particularly useful to step through *multiple arrays in parallel*. Use a plain [`FOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) loop with [`array_lower()` / `array_upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(UserResponseList, 1)
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', QuestionList[i], UserResponseID_List[i], UserResponseList[i];
END LOOP;
```

Since you created the array in the function, we *know* the index starts with 1 (default). Else, use:

```
FOR i IN array_lower(UserResponseList, 1) .. array_upper(UserResponseList, 1)
```

The index `i` is defined automatically, [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR)

> The variable **`name`** is automatically defined as type `integer` and exists
> only inside the loop.

Related cases with more information:

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784986/939860)
- [To ignore result in BEFORE TRIGGER of PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31892633/939860)

Comment: Thank you. New knowledge! 1. Index starts from 1 2. array_lower()/array_upper() are used in this way. I had read the manual in the document, but I did not understand. I though it was not related to my case. I'll be back and try your answer in my program within several hours.

Comment: @Sarit: Postgres array indexes are 1-based *by default* (unlike JSON arrays, for instance, which start with 0). But that's just the default. More: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12011569/939860

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have clicked green check, but my reputation is not reach threshold so I can not vote yet, sorry for that. Somewhat wonder, why I can't use @ sign infront of your name in small post here?

Comment: @Sarit: Because the author of the post (that's me) gets your comment automatically.