# Loop through slices of 2-dimensional array in plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6, array

How to loop through an array of arrays in a function and access its elements?

Below is the the function (this is only the relevant part).

```
create  or replace function public.whatwhatwhy(
        _fields character varying []
    ) returns void as 
$func$
declare strSQL text := '';
declare _field text := '';
begin 
    foreach _field in array _fields[:][1:2]
        loop 
            strSQL :=  'fieldname:' || _field[1] || ' stats: ' || _field[2] ;
            raise notice '% EXECUTING %', to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), strSQL;
        end loop;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

I want to call the function with:

```
select public.whatwhatwhy(ARRAY[
['total_pop', 'sum'],
['total_male_pop','sum'],
['median_female_age','median']
])
```

**Question**
How do I access e.g. *total_pop* and *sum* in my `_field`? I assumed the `_field` variable holds another array however I get an error:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: cannot subscript type text because it is not an array
>   Where: SQL statement "SELECT 'fieldname:' || _field[1] || ' stats: ' || _field[2]"

**Note**

I tried this statement, hoping that this solves the problem, but it seems to be identical to the statement above.

```
select public.whatwhatwhy(ARRAY[
ARRAY['total_pop', 'sum'],
ARRAY['total_male_pop','sum'],
ARRAY['median_female_age','median']
])
```

Comment: The argument of your function is defined as as array of character varying. Then, you cannot use an array of arrays.

Comment: How do you store this arrays? Is there any table? Could you post your table schema? And please tag your postgres version.

Comment: @McNets I do not store this array at all, it will only be passed to the function, where I need the information ```total_pop``` as a column name and ```sum``` as the name of an aggregation function. I use plpgsql to build my query string.

Comment: @Dario I thought the [] make it an array as in this example (however with INT[]) https://stackoverflow.com/a/571205/1623867

Comment: You are using an array as a key/value pair replacement. JSON or `hstore` would be better suited for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters.

[This SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191706/47647) helped me at the end to solve the problem.

- Declaring `_field` is not necessary.
- The `foreach` loop becomes a simple loop.
- Each field is addressed by `[i][1]` for the column name e.g. *total_pop* and `[i][2]` for the statistics e.g. *sum*.

The function has to be like this:

```
create  or replace function public.mj_rubbish(
        _fields character varying []
    ) returns void as 
$func$
declare strSQL text := '';
begin 
    for i in 1 .. array_upper(_fields,1)
        loop 
            strSQL :=  'fieldname:' || _fields[i][1] || ' stats: ' || _fields[i][2] ;
            raise notice '% EXECUTING %', to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), strSQL;
        end loop;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Will output:

> 00000: 2018-04-06 12:08:53 EXECUTING fieldname:total_pop stats: sum
>   00000: 2018-04-06 12:08:53 EXECUTING fieldname:total_male_pop stats: sum
>   00000: 2018-04-06 12:08:53 EXECUTING fieldname:median_male_age stats: median
>   00000: 2018-04-06 12:08:53 EXECUTING fieldname:median_female_age stats: median

Answer (score 3):

A `FOR` loop over `array_upper(_fields,1)` like you found is a simple and good option.

Even simpler for your case (for Postgres 9.1 or later): **`FOREACH`** with **`SLICE`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

> With a positive `SLICE` value, `FOREACH` iterates through slices of the
>   array rather than single elements.

Your function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mj_rubbish(_fields text[])
   RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   m text[];
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _fields
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '% EXECUTING fieldname: %, stats: %', now()::text, m[1], m[2];
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This also works regardless of actual array indices - which do no have to start with *1* (but do by default).

Related:

- [Loop over array dimension in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop/9784986#9784986)
- [Step through multiple arrays in parallel with FOREACH](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111410/step-through-multiple-arrays-in-parallel-with-foreach/111936#111936)
- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1/44448230#44448230)